# is it good practice to define a property using var keyword in oo php

Tags: php, oop

i came across this code,and was wondering if it is a good practice to define properties this way.How do the access modifiers(public,protected,private) work with this keyword definition?

```
class Brick {
  var $sample_attribute;
}
```

Comment: That's PHP 4 syntax and is obsolete. Do not use it. http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.properties.php

Answer (score 1):

No it's not a good practice, since this is only left in php for backwards compatibility for php 4.

`var` will be threaded as `public`. And as you can read in the manual it's no longer required, so it's just from a older php version.

You even have note in the [manual](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.properties.php) for this:

> **Note:**
>   In order to maintain **backward compatibility with PHP 4, PHP 5** will still accept the use of the **keyword var** in property declarations instead of (or in addition to) public, protected, or private. **However, var is no longer required.** In versions of PHP from 5.0 to 5.1.3, the use of var was considered deprecated and would issue an E_STRICT warning, but since PHP 5.1.3 it is no longer deprecated and does not issue the warning.
>   I**f you declare a property using var** instead of one of public, protected, or private, then **PHP 5 will treat the property as if it had been declared as public.**